# Sails.js group routes in v1, v2, etc

Tags: javascript, routes, sails.js, nested-routes

I have API with Sails.js and I want to wrap all my routes in `v1`. Is it possible?

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

`routes.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports.routes = {
    '/v1': {                                //
      'get /cron': 'CronController.start'   // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    },                                      //

    'get /cron': 'CronController.start'     // this works
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge of Sails the only way to wrap all of your routes in `/v1` is to first ensure the `actions` boolean in `config/blueprints.js` is set to `true` (it is by default), and then further down in that file set the `prefix` string to `"/v1"`. Here is the [documentation detailing this config](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.html).

Note that having the `actions` boolean set to `true` causes Sails to generate GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE routes for the action, make sure to use policies to ensure no unsafe logic is exposed in this way.

Comment: Yea but blueprints is totally not what I want tho. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, but just make sure I'm being clear, and in case you didn't know, you don't have to use the REST routes with this, enabling the action blueprints would just give `/cron` the route prefix and the GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE verb routes in the given example.